# how to show logs in staging and not in production environment using Java LOGGER

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

We are developing the Springbboot application and my requirement is to show logs in staging and don't show few logs in producation.
Note: Looger level is INFO in both environment

We are setting 1 variable from YML file and its true in staging and false in PROD

Comment: What is exact challenge you are facing ?

Comment: unless you use different levels of logging, you cannot enable or disable only particular logs of same level ( i mean INFO ) depending on your profile. you can use info logs for production which will print only certain things and debug should be used in dev - that will print more detailed things, certainly this is the recommended approach.
Other solution is to use a boolean flag and set it's value depeding on dev environment or production and use it to print logs with details or filtered details, but it is not recommended approach.

Comment: Do go through official documentation on Spring Boot - [Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging)

Comment: can you share your yaml file along wih your pom.xml ?